# How to upload data asset into scoring script of Azure endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy a machine learning model in a endpoint. I have registered the model as "ModelTest". I am trying to predict sales based on historic data, so to predict next month I pass to the model the sales for the previous six months. To do this I need to access the historic data.
The historic data is uploaded in a data asset in Azure.

I understand that I should write my preprocessing code in the scoring script, but I can't find the right way to upload the historic data from the data asset to the endpoint.

I tried to deploy the model without preprocessing by following the example in the Azure documentation and it works smoothly.

```
import os
import logging
import json
import numpy
import pickle


def init():
    """
    This function is called when the container is initialized/started, typically after create/update of the deployment.
    You can write the logic here to perform init operations like caching the model in memory
    """
    global model
    # AZUREML_MODEL_DIR is an environment variable created during deployment.
    # It is the path to the model folder (./azureml-models/$MODEL_NAME/$VERSION)
    # Please provide your model's folder name if there is one
    model_path = os.path.join(
        os.getenv("AZUREML_MODEL_DIR"), "ModelTest.sav"
    )
    # deserialize the model file back into a sklearn model
    model = pickle.load(open(model_path,'rb'))
    logging.info("Init complete")


def run(raw_data):
    """
    This function is called for every invocation of the endpoint to perform the actual scoring/prediction.
    In the example we extract the data from the json input and call the scikit-learn model's predict()
    method and return the result back
    """
    logging.info("model 1: request received")
    data = json.loads(raw_data)["data"]
    data = numpy.array(data)
    
    result = model.predict(data)
    logging.info("Request processed")
    return result.tolist()
```

I then tried to upload the data asset in the init function by using `pd.read_csv'. I have tried all three path in the "Data Sources" tab of the asset, but all of them give an error because the container can't access the data. For example using the following

```
    Data=pd.read_csv('https://machinelearnin6474979439.blob.core.windows.net/azureml-blobstore-b6321cf2-b0da-411e-97bb-9be13a8d1c89/UI/2023-06-26_132526_UTC/Data.csv'')
```

I get "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 409: Public access is not permitted on this storage account." while for the other paths it doesn't recognize them.

I think read_csv should work, given that `pickle.load` does, so I suppose it is a problem of using the right path.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on the task you are trying to do? 
You want preprocess the same data you are you are doing prediction or it's different data?
Please provide some more details in question such as what you have tried till now and what error you're getting, that would help in reproduce the issue.

Comment: I added some detail. I am just trying  to give predictionst based on historic data, so the user should give some parameters (like which article we are trying to predict) and the scoring script should calculate the previous sales of that article to then predict the next sales.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information, you are trying to access a data asset in scoring script using the URL of data asset.

`pd.read_csv()` will work if you give the dataset as input with environment path.
[image]

If you want to access the data asset directly in the scoring script, then one possible solution can be to with Dataset package by adding the below code in your init() function.
Below is a sample code snippet:

```py
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset
import pandas as pd

# Replace these values with your own
subscription_id = 'your_subscription_id'
resource_group = 'your_resource_group'
workspace_name = 'your_workspace_name'
dataset_name = 'your_dataset_name'

# Connect to your workspace
workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)

# Get the registered dataset
dataset = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, "test_dataset")

# Load the data into a pandas DataFrame
historic_data = dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()
historic_data
```

[image]

Other possible solution is to use SAS URL of for csv data file in init() and read with pd.read_csv().
[image]

Comment: Can you please expand on how to use the SAS URL? I will try with the Dataset package, but AFAIK it is used to access the workspace from outside, while the endpoint is already inside the workspace, in fact, I just need a path to upload the model. It feels like I should alse be able to access the data asset with just a path.

Comment: This it not working from the scoring script

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I thinks it's not possible to read from data asset, however, you can read from model asset. So register the historical data you need with the model, and you will be able to read it same way as you read the model.